# npm run watch terminal error, "did you forget to signal async completion", can anyone answer please?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp-watch, hyperapp

I am using a developer kit for a tutorial project. I typically use this same kit but sometimes different versions but normally it works ok. This time we are using hyperapp and I am having this issue where, when I run 'npm run watch' I get "did you forget to signal async completion?" in the terminal.
The kit has node, npm, gulp and tons of other stuff.
Anyways.. this is what's in the App.js file (there is not alot of syntax yet we are just starting the tutorial)

```
import { h, app } from 'hyperapp';
import Header from './Header.js';

export default function App({ state, actions }) {
    return (
        <div class={'app'}>
            <header state={state} actions={actions} />

    );
}
```

and this is in my Header.js file

```
import { h, app } from 'hyperapp';

export default function Header({ state, actions }) {
    return (
        <header>Header comp</header>
    );
}
```

And when I call npm run watch on terminal I get the error and it does not run watch or open my localhost page.
[Here is an image of my terminal error after I enter 'npm run watch'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5CK4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is this in React.js?

If so try closing the div properly, and Use capital letters for using custom components. if you give **h** it will consider it as a html header tag instead of Header component you created. See code below

```
    import { h, app } from 'hyperapp';
    import Header from './Header.js';

    export default function App({ state, actions }) {
        return (
            <div class={'app'}>
                <Header state={state} actions={actions} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: OMG man/women thank you!! You are a saint. That worked.. No it is not React, it is Hyperapp. Either way it worked.. thank you..

Comment: I'm a Mr. :p . Welcome.